# Blog page is not showing properly

Tags: blog-page, custom-header, wp-blog-header.php

I am working on my site http://coregroupus.com/blog/
due to some problem my blog page is not displaying posts properly. Its showing the content of some other page in header, however all the posts are okay, like if we see them here http://coregroupus.com/reducing-taxable-income/
http://coregroupus.com/profit-sharing-plans/

Please help me to get this issue fixed.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

It's in your css:

```
body.blog article .entry-summary {
    position: absolute;
body.blog article .entry-header {
    position: absolute;
```

change it to relative.